# Does each table row need a ID?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I've seen that almost every database entry has a ID field which auto-increments.

Is this really required?

If not, what is it useful for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's useful for finding that specific row later. If you have other values that are guaranteed unique for each row, you don't necessarily need an extra id column, since you can use the other column as the primary (unique) key.

But, the advantage of the auto-incrementing id column is that it's
a) unique for each row, and
b) never changes.

Take StackOverflow for instance. Every question has an ID (this one is 6886017), and uses both the ID and the title in the URL. So there can easily be two questions with the same title, because their IDs will still be unique. An you can even change the title of a question, and old links to it will still work, because what StackOverflow is really looking at, is the ID part of the URL, not the title part.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not really required, but if a row in a different table needs to reference that row, it's a reasonably good way to uniquely (unique in that table, at least) identify that row.

Comment: It's useful for other things that need a way to identify a row besides cross-table references. For example, if there's a specific row you want to delete, you can just add the `id=1234` or whatever its ID is to the `where` clause.

Comment: Not only a different table but also your documents might need this id. E.g. when you build an HTML page, and form elements have this id as value so you can delete user#123 or enter page #345.

Comment: @icktoofay: If you add the phrase "unique identifier" I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient (`WHERE id = 123` instead of `WHERE name = 'blah' and somethingelse = 'foo'`) and besides that, integer indexes are usually very performant compared to e.g. string indexes. Besides that

Comment: but usually when you get something from the db, you want to do it by a name or another relevant field. The ID looks like something "internal"

Comment: @laura: It is in some respects "internal" to the system, but it's internal to the system _you're_ building; not internal to database itself. I.e. MySQL doesn't care if you use an ID column or not, but it's of great use to yourself to have a unique ID for everything

Comment: If you want to get a column by name/whatever, put an index on that column. But for example take a table storing users with their real names. It's not too unlikely that two users have the same name. So you need the ID to identify them in a unique way.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: ID numbers and names follow: {1, 'Amy Winehouse'} {2713, 'Amy Winehouse'}. One of them died recently. Which one? You can't tell. The id number *distinguishes* the rows, but it doesn't *identify* the person.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with relational databases you need to be able to uniquely identify each row. In many cases you can pick one or mode data columns that will uniquely identify a row for you. That is called `natural key`. If you don't have an easy way to identify each row, then you can introduce your own column with sole purpose of doing this identification. That's called `synthetic key` and that's the id column with auto increment that you are asking about.

It is not required for as long as you have an alternative way to identify each row. It may be possible to have rows that are indistinguishable from each other but that would greatly reduce value of relational database paradigm. Also it does not have to be auto incremented number. Often unique id string is used such as UUID.

Answer (score 1):

"ID" means identifier. In the context of relational database design tuples (rows) within a relation are uniquely identifiable by keys and every relation must have at least one key.

Tables without keys would permit duplicate rows, which leads to ambiguity, inaccurate results and problems correctly identifying the real world entities which the rows are intended to describe. Keys are therefore an imporant aspect of data integrity for any database table.

Note however that a key does *not* have to be a single column and nor does it have to be "auto-incrementing". Those features have nothing much to do with choosing good keys for your tables.

Comment: I'd only add that a table whose *only* key is an id number allows duplicate data without allowing a duplicate row. Depending on the application, that *might* be the worst of all possible worlds.

Comment: @Catcall, Depends what you mean by "id number". Lots of things are identified by numbers. "Id number" could mean a natural key as well as a surrogate one.

Comment: Good point. I should have said, "A table whose only key is an *artificial* id number allows duplicate data without allowing a duplicate row." (I try to reserve the term *surrogate key* to describe a key that takes the place of a natural key. I don't always succeed.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not required however it very recommended. It is very useful for keeping rows unique for indexing, updated, deletes, etc.

Here is some helpful information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key

Answer (score 0):

The ID field is generally a primary key for the field. It identifies that specific field in that specific table, the primary key cannot repeat. It can also be used as a foreign key to help join tables.

Here's a simple introduction:http://www.opensourcevarsity.com/mysqldba/l8primaryforeignkey

Comment: "primary key for the field"? A key is a set of attributes. It's a property of a table, not a field. A primary key doesn't identify a "specific field", it is a set of attributes, the values of which identify unique *tuples* (i.e. rows), not fields.